# Pattern Matching Where am i wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this datas inserted into table named princess_bet_football
`TABLE ONE
      TABLE NAME:princess_bet_football
      ID_NO  TIME         TEAMS                        HOME   DRAW   AWAY
      131 23:30:00 UTC DE CAJAMARCA v Sport Rosario    1.57   3.45   6.28
      132 23:30:00 Atletico FC v Cucuta Deportivo      4.13   3.14   1.88
      133 01:15:00 America Mineiro MG v Figueirense FC 1.58   3.38   6.33
      134 02:00:00 EC Taubate SP v EC Agua Santa SP    2.44   3.09   2.81
      135 02:00:00 New York Red Bulls II v Toronto FC II 1.56 3.73   5.44
      136 02:30:00 Santiago Wanderers v Cobresal       1.56   3.78   5.44
      137 02:30:00 Luverdense MT v Parana Clube PR     2.11   2.95   3.64
      138 02:30:00 Santa Cruz PE v Boa Esporte Clube   1.90   3.06   4.27
      139 03:00:00 Monarcas Morelia v CF Monterrey     3.17   3.06   2.22
      140 03:00:00 Botafogo PB v Fortaleza CE          2.06   3.06   3.59`

There is second table named mk_bet which is empty but there are raw data to be inserted in csv and those data are as follows

`TABLE TWO
    Atletico FC v Cucuta Deportivo                 4    3.5 1.75
    Deportivo Capiata v Nacional Montevideo        2.3  3.2 2.8
    Americade Quito v Aucas                       2.38  3.2 2.7
    America Mineiro v Figueirense                 1.62  3.5 4.75
    EC Taubate v Agua Santa                       2.3   3.3 2.63
    Orlando City v Atlanta United                 2.6   3.25    2.4
    General Diaz v Cerro Porteno                 3.8    3.25    1.83
    Santa Cruz v Boa                                1.91    3.3 3.6
    Santiago Wanderers v Cobresal                 1.5   4.2 5
    Monarcas Morelia v Monterrey                 3.25   3.2 2.05
    Ceara v Goias                                 1.73  3.3 4.33
    LDU Loja v Olmedo                               1.36    4.33    7
    Barcelona SC v Fuerza Amarilla                1.2   5.25    13
    Tigre v Patriotas                                2.5    2.8 2.8
    Atlante v Cafetalerosde Tapachula               1.95    3.25    3.5
    Boyaca Chico v Universitario Popayan        1.67    3.5 4.5
    Leones Negros v Correcaminos                1.95    3.3 3.4
    Venados v Minerosde Zacatecas                2.2    3.3 2.88
    Tijuana v Cruz Azul                              2.15   3.1 3.1
    Avondale Heights U20 v Bentleigh Greens U20      1.75   4   3.5`

So inorder to insert data to be inserted in table 2 it must exist in table one, there is a query which perform that task which is seen below

```
 PHP CODES

$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "mkbf.csv"; 
$row = 0;

if (($handle = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {   
    $row++;
    if($row == 1) continue;
    if ($data[0]) { 
     //Mysql Start
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `princess_bet_football` WHERE `TEAMS` LIKE '%$data[0]%'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
     while ($newArray = mysql_fetch_array($query))
     {
       $id_no=$newArray['ID_NO'];
       $sql="insert into mkeka_bet_football (ID_NO,TEAMS,HOME,DRAW,AWAY)VALUES('$id_no','".addslashes($data[0])."','".addslashes($data[1])."','".addslashes($data[2])."','".addslashes($data[3])."')"; 

     if (mysql_query($sql))
     {
     echo "<b>";
     echo "RECORD(S) ADDED ";
     echo "</b>";
     }
     else
     {
       echo "<b>";
       echo "RECORD(S) NOT ENTERED SOMETHING WENT WRONG";
       echo "</b>";
       echo "<br>";
       echo mysql_error();
     }
  }
}
//Mysql End
} 
}
fclose($handle);
```

As you saw above Table one already contain data table two is empty, inorder to insert data in table two that record should exist in table one, in php code above it does the work of check if record to be inserted in table two exist in table one if it exist it will be inserted in table two if it is not exist it will not be inserted, so my problem is from the above php codes it does check if records exist but it consistency for example if i took those codes and run in my phpadmin only two records will be entered in table 2 while it is supposed to enter like five records that exist in table one and table two hope my explanation is clear now, Any thoughts or new idea how to implement this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dump the file into a temporary table and use this query.
INSERT INTO mkeka_bet_football (ID_NO,TEAMS,HOME,DRAW,AWAY) SELECT A.ID_NO , A.TEAMS , A.HOME , A.DRAW , A.AWAY FROM princess_bet_football A JOIN mkeka_bet_football_temp B ON A.TEAMS = B.TEAMS;

Comment: If i use this query wont it bring problem in Case Sensitivity issue and Space issues? Because there are time i find names look  the same but another one might have some additional characters? With this query from my understanding the name from table one should be the same as data in table two by considering space and case sensitivity please correct me if am wrong